# How to collect flows in ViewModel with a parameter

Tags: android, mvvm, coroutine, kotlin-flow

I have a function in repository that returns a response either from network or remote datasource based on a parameter.

BookRepository:

```kotlin
suspend fun getBooks(isNetwork: Boolean) : Flow<Books>
```

I want to collect this in View model but each time the ViewModel method is called a new coroutine is created. I am aware that I should be mapping the flow before exposing to UI layer but how would I then pass parameter to the function?

BookViewModel:

```kotlin
fun getBooks(isNetwork: Boolean) {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            bookRepository.getBooks(isNetwork).collectLatest { books ->
             ...
            }
        }
}
```

Here the getBooks function is also used to make a network call and needs to be invoked multiple times. Each time getBooks from ViewModel is called a new coroutine is created and hence multiple observers are created.

Comment: Where is `isNetwork` coming from? Where are you trying to call `getBooks` from?

Comment: @ianhanniballake I want to call getBooks from view model in a fragment. It is called both on page load and on user action to refresh the page. `isNetwork` comes from a fragment it is decided if user chooses to force refresh then it is set to true. I guess it can be tied to a user event either click or pull to refresh.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You shouldn't be using `viewModelScope.launch` for this at all - that would continue to run even after your UI disappears (i.e., when your screen goes onto the back stack or when the user hits the home button).

Instead, you need to:

1. Keep your `isNetwork` state in your ViewModel. Expose a setter so your UI can update the state when the user requests network data.
2. Use that `isNetwork` state as the input into your call to `bookRepository.getBooks`
3. Expose that final state to your UI using `shareIn` to ensure that you are always returning a single Flow object that keeps cached data over a config change as per [the Android SharedFlow guide](https://developer.android.com/kotlin/flow/stateflow-and-sharedflow#sharein).

This would mean your `ViewModel` looks more like:

```
class YourViewModel(
  // Let's assume you are using some sort of dependency injection
  bookRepository: BookRepository
) : ViewModel() {

  // Keep your internal state as an observable MutableStateFlow
  // here defaulting to isNetwork = false
  private val isNetworkFlow = MutableStateFlow(false)

  // Allow your UI to change whether isNetwork is true or false
  public fun useNetwork(isNetwork) {
    isNetworkFlow.value = isNetwork
  }

  // Transform each output of isNetworkFlow into a
  // new Flow from the bookRepository
  public val booksFlow: Flow<List<Books>> = isNetworkFlow.flatMapLatest { isNetwork ->
    bookRepository.getBooks(isNetwork)
  }.shareIn( // Only collect from the booksRepository when the UI is visible
    viewModelScope,
    started = SharingStarted.WhileSubscribed(5000),
    replay = 1
  )
}
```

Now your UI can `collect` on `booksFlow` in `onViewCreated` and call `useNetwork(true)` to swap to the network source whenever the user wants to.

This same approach can be used for other state too if you have a more complicated case (e.g., a boolean might not be enough).

Comment: This makes sense, small follow-up when using StateFlows and emitting the same values wouldn't trigger observers right? In this case is user refreshes twice there the request would be triggered only 1 time for the first time `isNetwork` is set to true. 

Should I be using LiveData here instead? Since I want to trigger observer for each change. I am unaware how to achieve this using flows.

Comment: Generally, your repository layer should already be handling observing it's source of data (e.g., getting a push message whenever data on the server changes, thus automatically loading new data), so this whole problem fixes itself, but you might consider following that last paragraph's advice and doing something more than just a boolean - for example a data class of isNetwork + the current timestamp that would be unique for each useNetwork call